# How to set an std::vector with another one, where the two are vectors of different classes?

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector

Is there a way to set an std::vector with another one, where the two are vectors of different classes?

```
struct A {
   int a;
};

struct B {
   int a, b;
   B(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}
};

int commonB = 123;

std::vector<A> va;
std::vector<B> vb;

// Fill va...

// Code I would like to optimise:
for(size_t i = 0; i < va.size(); ++i) {
    vb.push_back(B(va[i].a, commonB));
}
```

Anything like (pseudo-code):

```
vb = va;
```

with the B::b values uninitialised?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to optimize. You still need to loop over `va` to assign its elements to `vb`. The only thing you could still do is call `resize` and use `emplace_back`, but those would not really provide any substantial performance improvements.

Comment: You seem to want to [*transform*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) one vector into another.

Comment: You cannot leave `B::b` values uninitialized though, because `B` doesn't have a constructor that allows this.

Comment: By "optimize" (in the comments) do you mean that you want to make your code faster, or just more elegant/compact?

Comment: Your **title** says you want to **initialize** the vector, but your **code** **assigns** to the vector. To initialize the new vector, first write a constructor for `B` that takes a `const A&` and does whatever it is that you need to do. Then `std::vector<B> vb(va.begin(), va.end());` will initialize `vb` with the appropriate values from `va`.

Comment: @AnT - Yes, and it clearly does something other than _leaving `B::b` values uninitialized_, which is what OP explicitly asks for.

Comment: @AnT: possibly both.

Comment: @PeteBecker: thank you, I fixed my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just like to point out, that since range-based for loops, I haven't really had much desire to use simple algorithms like transform very often. I hope you can see why.

```
std::transform(va.begin(), va.end(), std::back_inserter(vb),
    [commonB](A x) -> B { return B(x.a, commonB); });

for (auto& e : va)
    vb.emplace_back(e.a, commonB);
```

Comment: I agree.  range based for loops make simple iterate and do something pretty easy.  Being able to take advantage of `emaplce_back` is also nice.

Comment: I just noticed Chris Drew had almost the same answer, and deleted it. I wonder why.

Comment: Yes, I had the same answer but saw the bit in the question about leaving `B::b` values uninitialized and thought I must have misunderstood the question.

Comment: You should probably call `reserve` though.

Answer (score 3):

`transform` from `<algorithm>` header together with `back_inserter` from `<iterator>` can be used to make this like:

```
std::transform(va.begin(), va.end(), std::back_inserter(vb),
    [](A x) -> B { return B(x.a, commonB); });
```

**UPDATE**

If `commonB` has not the global scope, its name should be captured (written in the square brackets of lambda definition):

```
std::transform(va.begin(), va.end(), std::back_inserter(vb),
    [commonB](A x) -> B { return B(x.a, commonB); });
```

Comment: Maybe mention `reserve` should be called on the vector you are copying to so eliminate reallocation's in the vector.

Comment: Do you know if there is any performance improvement using `std::transform`, or is the generated binary equivalent?

Comment: @Pietro With optimizations turned on it should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get much more optimal. You can make sure enough space is reserved in `vb` upfront to avoid unnecessary reallocations and use a range-based for loop and `emplace_back` to make the loop more concise:

```
vb.reserve(va.size());
for (const auto& a : va)
    vb.emplace_back(a, commonB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generalise with with a transform function and a lambda.

All will be perfectly optimised when you compile with -O2 or better:

Note the use of `reserve()` to prevent reallocations while the vector grows.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct A {
   int a;
};

struct B {
   int a, b;
   B(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}
};

template<class TransformFunction>
std::vector<B> transform_copy(std::vector<A>& source, TransformFunction&& trans)
{
    std::vector<B> result;
    result.reserve(source.size());
    std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(result), trans);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int commonB = 123;
    auto transform_function = [commonB](A const& source) {
        return B(source.a, commonB);
    };

    std::vector<A> va;
    std::vector<B> vb = transform_copy(va, transform_function);

}
```

You can also make it more expressive. Lambdas are an easy and optimally efficient way to express human-readable concepts like lazy functions (like Haskell et. al.):

```
auto vb = transform_to_Bs(va, with_common_b(123));
```

Which can be implemented thus:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    int a, b;

    B(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}
};


extern std::vector<A> get_As();

int main() {

    auto with_common_b = [](auto &&commonB) {
        return [commonB](auto &&a) {
            return B(a.a, commonB);
        };
    };

    auto transform_to = [](auto &&target, auto &&source, auto &&transform_function) {
        target.reserve(source.size());
        std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(),
                       std::back_inserter(target),
                       std::forward<decltype(transform_function)>(transform_function));
    };

    auto transform_to_Bs = [transform_to](auto &&va, auto &&transform_function) {
        std::vector<B> result;
        transform_to(result, va, std::forward<decltype(transform_function)>(transform_function));
        return result;
    };

    std::vector<A> va = get_As();

    auto vb = transform_to_Bs(va, with_common_b(123));
}
```

Applying perfect forwarding here is a gross over-optimisation. The compiler will in actual fact elide all redundant copies of function objects.